# How can I simplify the registration of a large set of closed generic versions of the same open generic implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container, fluent-interface

Is there a fluent way of writing the following:

```cs
var someTypes = GetType()
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(x => someFilter == true);

foreach(var someType in someTypes)
{
    var genericInterface = typeof(IFoo<>).MakeGenericType(someType);

    var genericImplementation = typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(someType);

    container.Register(
       Component.For(genericInterface)
            .ImplementedBy(genericImplementation));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should to it

```
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(IFoo<>))
      .ImplementedBy(typeof(Foo<>))
);
```

Comment: thx but ... I am not interested in the type Foo<>, I am registering the type that is returned from the MakeGenericType method

Answer (score 3):

a `IGenericServiceStrategy` is what you're after (on top of what @maxlego said, which is correct)

[See this](http://kozmic.net/2013/07/23/on-castle-windsor-and-open-generic-components/) for details and example.